# How did Monica know how to operate Carol's "designer"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

In *Captain Marvel*, we see Monica doing "fashion designing" for her aunt Carol. What's strange is that how does a kid with nil exposure to Kree tech know how to operate the "designer device".

It could be said that she was doing random guesswork. But, at a point, Carol says "Let's copy your T-shirt's pattern" to Monica and in the very first try Monica is able to achieve the exact pattern. This just cannot be termed as random.

Comment: It's a visual display for changing the color of an object. If you look closely, the colors of the display are the same as the colors of the suit. It's not a mapping that requires knowledge of Kree programming languages.

Comment: @Adamant Whilst that seems partially true, Monica does seem to swipe a lot of colours at the same time if I'm remembering correctly so there might be more to it than that.

Comment: You never seen kids figure out inscrutable computer interfaces really fast? Snapchat's entire existence relies on this ability.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite In the 90s, though?

Comment: @AzorAhai Even moreso in the 90s.

Comment: @AzorAhai: yup, kids did not spontaneously evolve this ability in 2007. We had Gameboys!

Comment: @AzorAhai The idea that only kids could use technology, and that they had to teach their parents how to do it, was a standard recurring cliche in the 90's. Far more than it is now.

Comment: @AdmiralJota I was more wondering about the touch-based interface that would be pretty foreign to anyone back then.

Answer (score 30):

I have tweeted Andy Park, Marvel Studios Director of Visual Development & Concept Artist, who worked on *Captain Marvel* and this is what he has had to say:

> [image: Andy Park's tweet which is quoted below]
>
> **@CarrotLethal:** @andyparkart Hello, I've got a quick question you might be able to answer. How does Monica know how to use the designer on Vers' suit? Thanks!
>
> **@andyparkart:** I assume it was more Carol letting her have fun with it. The ability of the suits was for camouflage purposes so I’m sure the alien tech allows for intuitive color adjustments rather than Carol having to scroll through specific colors. So the suit can adapt to Monica’s shirt
>
> **@AH_AdamHughes:** I just assumed the suit has an “I feel lucky” button, like the Google home page
>
> **@andyparkart:** Woah! I never even knew about that button! But yes.. her suit has the Kree equivalent of that button
>
> <sub>[Twitter, @andyparkart](https://twitter.com/andyparkart/status/1111016597328584704)</sub>

Considering this it would appear that three things were going on:

1. The suit was intuitive enough that it was easy for Monica to see what to do.
2. The suit had a "I'm feeling lucky" button and so Monica didn't necessarily choose the colours rather than the suit picked random ones.
3. Monica didn't necessarily chose the final colours, rather the suit itself adapted to her t-shirt.

Comment: My memory confirms. It is definitely Carol who adopts the pattern and Monica is basically just randomly swiping and looking for the outcome. Yes, the device shows colours. But they are more of a confined range of, say, shades of red, and the panel more or less completely (there seemed a small part close to the hand that does not IIRC) changes colours depending on input. I remember well because I wondered how the hell this is supposed to work.

Comment: No, she was doing random things until Carol asked her to do a specific color scheme(Copy your T-shirt's pattern).  Then she was able to perfectly match it first try.  So maybe Kree tech is just that intuitive but its a bit odd she was that good at it that fast.

Comment: @Chris _"then Carol uses the device to copy Monica's t-shirt."_

Comment: I agree the scene didn't really come across as I expect it was intended, but I do also agree that this was how it was intended. ^_^

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I remember Monica used it to copy her shirt.  I also remember thinking that they should have had Carol do it because its weird Monica could be that good that fast.

Comment: @Chris Maybe it's me forgetting how the scene played out but I think Carol does it. Will try and find the scene somewhere for a re-watch.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The scene is in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=45&v=QO_3gwtjjlA

Comment: Monica was the one who did it.

Comment: @Chris Wow that is an awful copy. S'pose you're right though. I'm gonna leave this answer as is for the moment whilst I'm waiting on some more stuff to edit in but feel free to add your own answer with this information if you can focus it onto the question yourself.

Comment: Two random thoughts: 1) low-level psychic interface; 2) Carol does it and just pretends Monica did it because she's a kid

Comment: As an aside, I've seen my 2 year old, who has trouble with language, access features in an iPad that I didn't know existed.  I work in IT.  I wouldn't be shocked at anything a kid does with technology anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The designer shows a rainbow from which the colors are selected. From experimenting several times with the device and seeing what certain touches do, Monica figures out what she needs to do to select the colors she wants.

Here is a screenshot of Monica beginning to select the final colors. You can see both the colors on the designer and Monica's red sleeve (click to enlarge):

[image]

Comment: You might want to get a better image as that one is so washed out you can't really see anything.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I can get more images, but none of better quality right now. When it comes out on BluRay there will be better images out there and I will be able to get something better.